# Is it possible to select and submit a form using only class as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I found i was unable to select and submit a form using only class as a selector:

```
$("form.class").submit(...)
```

does not work... while:

```
$("form#id").submit(...)
```

works like a charm.

What gives?

Comment: I know it's stupid, but are you sure you 1) actually have a form with that class, and 2) that you only have ONE form with that class?

Comment: Show your HTML... Indeed it is possible to select elements just by class...

Comment: I can *not* confirm this, see http://jsfiddle.net/uUBJL/. Tested on Firefox 25.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm on iPad, no (obvious) console; what is 'this' that you can't confirm?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: yes, it is possible to select and submit a form using only a class as selector

```html
<form id="f1" class="test">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="f2" class="test">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```js
$('form.test').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' submitted');
});

$('form.test').submit();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUBJL/)

This binds the `onsubmit` for both forms and then triggers the submit for the two forms. The output on the console (Firefox 25) is

> f1 submitted
>   f2 submitted

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$('.classname').on('submit', function(){...});
```

Comment: Please, don't sign your answers/questions (that's what your user card is for), and this is exactly the same as was posted in the question, with a less-specific selector.